# How to send raw JSON data with a post request using mechanize in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to POST JSON data to a api using a python script. I'm using python 2 and **mechanize** package.

```
import mechanize
import json, logging, sys, urllib

br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'url_here'
headers = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'),
('Content-Type', 'application/json')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_debug_responses(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_http(True)
logger = logging.getLogger("mechanize")
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
body = {"audience":{"name":"asd","criteria":[{"category":"common","label":"Industry","tags":[{"tag":"Information Technology","text":"Information Technology","score":2,"type":"Similar"},{"tag":"Computer Software","text":"Computer Software","score":2,"type":"Similar"},{"tag":"Marketing and Advertising","text":"Marketing and Advertising","score":2,"type":"Similar"}],"type":"input-group","icon":"restaurant_menu","operation":"include","suggestions":True,"related":False,"multiple":True,"rankings":True,"showStrictness":True,"strict":False,"stub":{"tags":[],"values":[]},"values":["Information Technology","Computer Software","Marketing and Advertising"],"field":"industry","scope":"companies"},{"category":"common","label":"Contact Location","type":"location-group","icon":"person_pin_circle","operation":"include","multiple":True,"suggestions":True,"related":False,"tip":"Find people based on their location. You can filter by Country, and Region / City (for example, San Francisco Bay Area).","options":[{"value":"country","label":"Country","placeholder":"e.g... United States, Australia"},{"value":"locality","label":"Region / City","placeholder":"e.g... San Francisco, Toronto"}],"stub":{"tags":[],"values":[]},"tags":[],"values":["India","United States of America","United Kingdom"],"field":"country","childField":"country","scope":"contacts"},{"category":"tech","label":"Technology Used","type":"input-group","operation":"include","suggestions":True,"related":False,"icon":"power","multiple":True,"rankings":True,"placeholder":"e.g... Salesforce, jQuery, Ruby","tip":"Find companies based on specific web-based technologies they use. Note: This filter will narrow your search significantly. Any companies that dont use the technology you enter will be excluded from the results. ","stub":{"tags":[],"values":[]},"tags":[{"tag":"jQuery","text":"jQuery","score":2,"type":"Similar"},{"tag":"Angular JS v2","text":"Angular JS v2","score":0,"type":"Similar"}],"values":["jQuery","Angular JS v2"],"field":"technology","scope":"companies"}],"purchasedLeads":0,"estimatedReach":0,"maxLeadsPerCompany":3,"searchLeadCount":500,"emailGuesserScope":"professional"}}
br.addheaders = headers
response = br.open(url, data=json.dumps(body))
print response
```

But I am unable to send the JSON data successfully. But when I'm sending the data using `urllib.urlencode()` then the data is being sent but not being processed in the server as the server is expecting JSON data through the post request. Please someone help with this.

Comment: Does it have to be `mechanize`? `requests` can make this really trivial if you want to explore that avenue.

Comment: Can I use requests to bypass robots.txt? and add headers?

Comment: You can set the headers to bypass `robots.txt`, yes.

Comment: Can you help me with that then??

Comment: Post the URL. Can't be doing some guessing here.

Comment: `https://api.growlabs.com/audiences?ut=**user_id**` this is the url. But you need an paid account. Can you just tell me the way to bypass robot.txt and sending json data using requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so decided to go with the requests module as suggested by @Manhattan. It's much easier and simple to send post request with json data using requests.

```
r = requests.post(url, json={"audienceId":id,"leadCount":500}, headers=h)
```

Here the json parameter is just a python dictionary. and headers is also a dictionary.
[Official documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/)

Comment: Above is also true for sending raw data using Body (similar like Postman POST request with params sent via Body and raw type).